# What is the reason behind my App rejection by AppStore?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

My App has been rejected again (for the forth time) recently because of the following reason:

**22.1: Apps must comply with all legal requirements in any location where they are made available to users. It is the developer's obligation to understand and conform to all local laws**

My app is a very simple and free mobile banking application that provides simple banking services such as balance inquiry, mini-statement, bill payment, etc. for bank customers of a bank in middle east. There is no purchasing or money transferring services in this App.

I've called AppStore review team several times, but they just repeat the mentioned reason and did not provide me with more detailed reasons.

Could anyone kindly guide me with this issue? How can I resolve this with my App?

**Edit 1:** It seems that as far as I use cryptography in my App, and regarding the fact the due to USA regulations, sending encrypted data outside USA without any license is in conflict with laws, the AppStore has rejected my App. What if I publish my App on AppStores outside USA? Do they have the same regulation as well?

**Edit 2:** As far as the Apps registered in different AppStores are kept in USA and their users will download them outside USA, all Apps are regarded as USA exports. So, if I publish my App on AppStores other than USA, the App will be rejected as well.

Comment: @MitchWheat What is wrong with being free and simple? There are lots of other Apps on Appstore that are simpler than my App !!!

Comment: I wouldn't trust a banking app. unless it came from my bank. PERIOD.

Comment: [Likely reason](http://tigelane.blogspot.se/2011/01/apple-itunes-export-restrictions-on.html).

Comment: @MitchWheat Right. it comes from the bank that i am developing the App for it.

Comment: @hsalimi in that case I think *they* should submit it, as legally identifiable owners of the infrastructure your app interacts with.

Comment: @fvu but how this can be done? I've found no item about this concern in AppStore anywhere.

Comment: @hsalimi Refer this issue back to the bank's management somehow, and let them sort it out with Apple - they'll have less trouble convincing Apple you are legit than you probably.  Because let's just face it, with all the commotion caused by security concerns and issues in different systems related to e-banking, it's a good think they are as cautious as they are, and reiterating the same arguments you've been using till now won't change a thing.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks for the link. What if I make my app available on other countries than usa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banking regulations in the United States are very stringent, especially after the last financial meltdown. Apple's agreement may contain clauses which stipulate you (as the developer) to adhere to all laws in the United States because Apple is a US company.

Yes, they could probably allow it given your in a separate country, and given you stipulate your app not be sold in the US. But they might not because it's not in their primary interest. Their primary interest to stay lawful comes before their interest to serve third-party application developers.

Also, your application might be reviewed inside the United States. US citizens are known to be fairly ignorant about the cultures of other countries. This might be a decision made by an ignorant US citizen based upon the words "middle east" and "bank".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I talked to apple representative and the rejection reason was EXACTLY what you've mentioned.

Comment: :) hopefully not the latter part.

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason was exactly the latter part. :=((

Comment: Sorry about that man. Don't feel so bad though, the banking industry is known to be pretty exclusive.

Answer (score 7):

The reason is because of Legal requirements. Please read the ￼￼￼[Appstore Guidelines](http://images.worldofapple.com/appstoreguidelines_9910.pdf).

This Links[(link1](http://www.coindesk.com/apple-to-create-virtual-currency-imoney/) [link2)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6813)may help you.

Easiest way to resolve this issue would probably be to decide which countries you want to make your app available in, research their local laws to see if any thing is illegal.

> What if I make my app available on other countries than usa?

You can easily mention/edit those details In itunes connect under **rights and pricing**. You can restrict the countries your app will be available in, untick any you don't want.

**Here are the screen shots.**

Please logg-in to iTunes and select your app and edit the below settings (2nd page of App details)

[image]

[image]